# TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object referenc

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.     at
>   RadioSkonto_fla::MainTimeline/onEnterFrame()[RadioSkonto_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:30]

There is the code!

http://radosi.lv/2/screen.png

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because, on the first call to onEnterFrame, fl_SC has not been defined - fl_SC is only set to s.play() when the user clicks play_btn.
Either check that fl_SC has been defined before checking a property of it, or change the sequence of events so that there's an instance of fl_SC at the first call to onEnterFrame.

Comment: add a trace immediately before the line that starts 'eqBarLeft1_bt.gotoAndStop...' ie: trace("fl_SC = "+fl_SC); It will trace out as undefined. It is trying to access a property of fl_SC BEFORE fl_SC is set, in the fl_ClickToPlaySound function. You can't access properties of an undefined object. You'll need to ensure it's defined before that point.

Comment: I'd suggest moving the ENTER_FRAME event listener to INSIDE the play_btn CLICK handler function, AFTER fl_SC is set.